# Authen Key Mifare 1K

Tags: vb.net

Now I try to change key of Mifare Card 1K 
with ACR128 reader and I push key with AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (Len = 16 charactor)
it Ok 
when I try to Authern with AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  (Len = 16 )
it ok I can Authen
BUT when I try to read data It can't access
it return code = "63 00" it mean to can not read

help me please !!!
(I use Mifare Card Programming it = sample code with VB programming from SDK)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

FF 0F 00 would make the access bits unwritable. The default is actually FF 07 80

Answer (score 0):

the Mifare key is composed as follow:

- 6 byte for key A
- 4 byte for Access Bits
- 6 byte for key B which is optional and can be set to 00

The Access bits define write / read rights you have for each data block and ev. the key you have to use to access those blocks.

Further details are on the NXP website available or directly at the following link: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S503x.pdf

A default Access Bits is usually FF 0F 00 that allow to write and read each block and to read and write key B.